# Number Theory: Divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm really having some trouble figuring out these problems:

1. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $14\mid (4a+3b)$. Prove or disprove $14\mid (30a-16b)$
2. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, Prove if $a\mid b^2$ then $a\mid b$.  (For this can't you just give a counter example by picking two integers? Therefore resulting in a rational number?)
3. There exists integers $x,y,z$ such that $172x+90y+222z = 722,199,441$

Any advice on would be greatly appreciated to approaching these problems.

Comment: Use latex please!

Comment: Are you supposed to prove the last two statements ? They are false.

Comment: For 2)  there are easy counterexamples. For 3) the left side is even and the right side is odd.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: In the future, please ask only one question at a time, unless the say $2$ questions are closely related. And please indicate what you have tried. For example you could have been more explicit about your approach to 2).

Comment: @AndréNicolas for 3, are you invoking some sort of theorem to get that answer or is it just some sort of property? Also for 2 is a counter example of letting a = 2 and b = 3 a valid counterexample?

Comment: It is obvious that for any integers $x,y,z$ the expression is even, since the coefficients are even. If you really want detail, note that the expression is equal to $2(86x+45y+111z)$. And of course the right side is odd, it ends in $1$. And an even integer cannot be equal to an odd integer. I guess that's a theorem, but I think proof is not needed. For 2), your example is not a valid counterexample, since $2$ does not divide $3^2$. But $a=4$, $b=2$ is a valid counterexample, or $a=4$ and $b=6$. In each case $a$ divides $b^2$ but $a$ does not divide $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 30a\!-\!16b\, =\, 4(\underbrace{4a\!+\!3b}_{\Large \color{#c00}{14}\,c}) + \color{#c00}{14}(a\!-\!2b)$

Comment: Thank you so much! Did you end up just figuring this out by trial and error, or is there some other way to go about getting this? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @Dean ${\rm mod}\ 14\!:\ 30a\equiv 16a\,$ so we need to multiply $\,4a+3b\,$ by $\,4\,$ to get $\,16a\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $16(4a+3b)+3(30a-16b)=154a=14(11a)$.

The other two questions are dealt with in comments.

Answer (score 0):

$\\ \text{ it probably isn't totally different then what was mentioned before but... } \\ 4a_1+3b_1=1 \text{ when } (a_1,b_1)=(1,-1) \\4(14)+3(-14)=14 \\ \text{ so } 4(14k)+3(-14k)=14k \text{ holds for integer } k \\ \text{ so } (a,b)=(14k,-14k) \\ \text{ then so } \\ 30a-16b=30(14k)-16(-14k)=14k(30+16) \\ \text{ therefore } 14|(30a-16b) \text{ when } 14|(4a+3b) $